# SPI connection is not working

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, clock

I am trying to establish an SPI connection using the Nucleo-F030R8 board but there's no signal coming out. How do you start the connection?

I did the configurations using STM32CUBE MX software and code it using TrueStudio. Is there any line of code apart from MX_SPI1_Init(); that is already automatically generated?

As for the pins I am sure it is not faulty as I tried to toggle each and they were visible in the logic analyzer but when I tried to send Data through SPI, even the clock doesn't get triggered.

is there a step that I missed in order for the clock to be triggered?

thanks for the help

Comment: Post the code. If the IO pins are set to SPI alternate mode, you should not be able to toggle them as GPIO. After initializing the IO pins, you should just be able to send a SPI byte, and see clock and data for it.

Comment: Study the SPI example projects for STM32F030R8-Nucleo in the STM32CubeF0 package, available from [STMicro](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef0.html) or [GitHub](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF0).